# How to add an hyperlink to a cell in an embedded table

Tags: html, hyperlink, html-table

I have created a basic table for a website but I would like to be able to click on the cells and be redirected to other pages within that website - basic hyperlinks. But I need to do it within the coding.

So, my table looks like this:

```
<td> Monday </td>
<td> Vicky </td>
<td> Bromley </td>
<td> 10.00-10.45am</td>
```

And then when the customer clicks on Bromley - I would like it to redirect them to the Bromley page  - http://www.boppintots.co.uk/#!/bromley.

Can someone help? I tried doing some of the hdef (?!?) things suggested under a different post but I am in way over my head here. Any specific help (i.e. the exact line of coding! :-) would be brilliant! I can then just replicate that for the remainder of my table.

(And, let's be honest here, I even had to look up/get help on how to get the code show up in this example...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the answers here already answer your question, but I thought it may be beneficial to you to go into a little detail so that you can understand the code you've been given.

In order to add a link to text, you need to wrap it in an achor `<a></a>` tag. It seems you have a basic understanding of HTML, but for the sake of being thorough I'll explain a little more.

An anchor tag can have many attributes, but the one you're looking for is the href attribute. (It stands for Hypertext Reference). [See W3 Schools for more info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

So, In order to achieve what you want to do, you'll need to use the code provided by others here:

```
<td> Monday </td> 
<td> Vicky </td> 
<td> <a href="http://www.boppintots.co.uk/#!/bromley.">Bromley</a> </td> 
<td> 10.00-10.45am</td>
```

For other links, simply replace the URL in the "speech marks".

I hope that this helps understand why the code works.

Comment: That is wonderful - thank you so much! Not only does it work but the explanation also makes sense and I can definitely apply it more confidently to the rest of the table. I really appreciate you taking the time to respond so thoroughly. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste below code:

```
<td> Monday </td> <td> Vicky </td> <td><a href="http://www.boppintots.co.uk/#!/bromley" />Bromley</a> </td> <td> 10.00-10.45am</td>
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for taking the time to do this - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td> Monday </td> <td> Vicky </td> <td><a href="http://www.boppintots.co.uk/#!/bromley."> Bromley </a></td> <td> 10.00-10.45am</td>
```

This should meet your requirement.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts in helping me - thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `a` tag inside your `td`

```
<a href="http://google.com">link text</a>
```

Comment: @Maddy How is that? Because I didn't paste exactly what the OP wanted?

Comment: Thank you very much for that - with the other posts I can understand how the coding is constructed now. Really appreciated.